# How pass the variable form config file form one plugin to another in Symfony?

Tags: plugins, symfony1, doctrine, symfony-1.4

I am new to Symfony 1.4

And I have a project in which I have 2 plugins. In first plugin named `myPlugin1` I have the `config` folder and in him the `app.yml` file, in which I have set a predefined "variable" like that:

```
all:
  carriage:
    cost:
      prepaid: 10
```

What I need is to pass this "variable" in a class from my other plugin, `myPlugin2`, which actually handle the payments costs.

How can I pass this "variable" to my class?

UPDATE: 
Can I do this like that? Or this can be used only in current plugin?

```
sfConfig::get('all_carriage_cost_prepaid')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the actual call must be:

```
sfConfig::get('app_carriage_cost_prepaid')
```

The starting prefix is related to the configuration file name. Source [here](http://www.symfony-project.org/gentle-introduction/1_4/en/05-Configuring-Symfony#chapter_05_accessing_the_configuration_from_code).

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I have found finally how to do it. Is like that:

```
$myarray = sfConfig::get('all_carriage_cost');
$thevalue = $myarray['cost'];
```

Here is the [source](http://www.prettyscripts.com/framework/symfony/symfony-sfconfig-and-max-hierarchical-levels-in-yml-file).